# Call onCreateView() on fragment that is inside a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have `viewpager` that has 4 fragments.
I have set the `offscreenPageLimit` to 4 and did not override `getItemPosition` of the adapter because I don't want them to be re-created every time when I change tabs.

Now, there will be a scenario when I want a particular `fragment` to be re-created (it means to call onCreateView).
That is before I select or when I select that fragment again.
How to do this?

Comment: I think it may impossible. Can you explain more about why you need to re-created Fragment again. Maybe we can found another way to achieve

Comment: Would you please provide the viewPagerAdapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this adapter. This recover to re-create fragment again.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Fragment[] fragments;
    private String[] titleList;
    private  int index;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] titleList){ // titleList is list of title of fragments
        super(fm);
        fragments = new Fragment[titleList.length];
        this.titleList = titleList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (fragments[position] == null){
                YourFragment  yourFragment = new YourFragment();
                fragment = yourFragment;
                fragments[position] = fragment;
            return fragment;
        }else{
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titleList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList[position].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do make a specific fragment re-create with this code? Lets I have a button and clicking on this will re-create the 2nd fragment. Then how?